# Let $G$ be a group such that $|G:Z(G)|=pq$ with $p<q$ primes. Prove that $q$ is congruent with $1$ modulo $p$.

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need help with this statement:

> Let $G$ be a group such that $|G:Z(G)|=pq$ with $p<q$ primes. Prove that $q \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

I took a subgroup $H$ of $G/Z(G)$ of order $p$ and I tried to apply the result $$|N_G(H):H| \equiv |G:H|\pmod p$$ but I'm stuck.

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881971/structure-of-a-group-g-of-order-pq-where-p-q-are-prime) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian).

Comment: You used the tag [tag:finite-groups] but you don't mention finite groups in the question . . .

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, @olasiu, but please [edit] the question to make it clear exactly where you are using finite groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By contradiction, suppose $q\not\equiv 1\pmod p$. Then $p\nmid q-1$. A group of order $pq$, with $p\nmid q-1$, [is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67129/1092170) (in the link, the roles of $p$ and $q$ are swapped). But if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then [$G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63087/1092170), and hence $|G/Z(G)|=1$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much!